# Linq statement: Inner function call conflicts with enclosing method name

Tags: vb.net, linq

Cryptic title, but I will start with the code that poses the problem and clarify afterwards:

```vb
Public ReadOnly Property Max As Double
    Get
        Dim res = (From a As Double() In Values Select a.Max).Max
        Return res
    End Get
End Property
```

`Values` is a jagged array of double,

```vb
Private Values()() As Double
```

that is initialized elsewhere. I want to use Linq to extract the overall maximum value.
The code above gives the following exception for the first `.Max`:

> BC30978   Range variable 'Max' hides a variable in an enclosing block or
>   a range variable previously defined in the query
>   expression.

If I change the Property name to something else like `GetMaximum` the error disappears.

**Why can't I call the `.Max` function for the `Double()` variable `a` that is selected from my jagged array? What does that call has to do in the slightest with the name of the method it is in?**

I am using Visual Studio Community 2015 on Windows 8.1.
Both answers in VB.NET or C# are much appreciated.

### Workarounds

As a workaround I can for example do the following:

```vb
Private Function GetMax(a As Double()) As Double
    Return a.Max
End Function
Public ReadOnly Property Max As Double
    Get
        Dim res = (From a As Double() In mvalues Select GetMax(a)).Max
        Return res
    End Get
End Property
```

No error there, so only the inner `.Max` is responsible for the error.

As mentioned earlier, that also works:

```vb
Public ReadOnly Property GetMax As Double
    Get
        Dim res = (From a As Double() In Values Select a.Max).Max
        Return res
    End Get
End Property
```

So it is a conflict between the first `.Max` and the property name.

Comment: I wonder if the reason this doesn't work is related to being able to use the function name as the return value, which works for properties too.  i.e. Instead of returning `res` you could just assign to `Max` - so there is a "variable" with the name `Max` already in scope that would confuse things.  Does `Dim res = (From a As Double() In Values Select MaxValue = a.Max).Max` work?

Comment: @Mark This works indeed and is a valuable insight. I however don't understand it exactly. I think you are correct about the "invisible" max variable and it messing up the query, but why is it resolved by assigning a specific name in the query?

Comment: I guess that the `Select` (a projection?) needs to give a name to each value selected, in case you want to use them later (e.g. `From a As Double() In Values Select a.Max Where Max < 1000`) - the result is (probably?) an anonymous type with properties for each value selected.  The default name for a function call is the function name (`Max` in this case), which causes the clash with the property name.  By giving an alias to the selected value, you can avoid the naming conflict.  We need a LINQ expert to jump in here! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I can't really explain why it's wrong what you're doing. I'm suspecting that the scope of the select "Max" is indeed conflicting with the property name, as you indicated. Maybe someone else can jump in with the explanation.

Either way, this seems to work well as an alternative:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Max As Double
    Get
        Return Values.Max(Function(a) a.Max)
    End Get
End Property
```